# Spring boot, spring data jpa application - how to check which connection pool being used?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, dbconnection

How to check what is the connection pool being used by default. I am using Spring boot version 1.5.4.RELEASE

UPDATE : https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-how-to-know-which-connection-pool-is-used/

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot uses HikariCP as the default connection pool, due to its remarkable performance and enterprise-ready features.

**Here’s how Spring Boot automatically configures a connection pool datasource:**

- Spring Boot will look for HikariCP on the classpath and use it by
  default when present
- If HikariCP is not found on the classpath, then Spring Boot will pick
  up the Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool, if it’s available
- If neither of these options is available, Spring Boot will choose
  Apache Commons DBCP2, if that is available

Source: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-tomcat-connection-pool

Comment: from the logs, how do you check? I am looking default one for Spring boot version 1.5.4.RELEASE

Comment: I got it from here, https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-how-to-know-which-connection-pool-is-used/

Comment: If I have Websphere  application, and I want to add Spring Boot with JPA, and to use the existing WAS connection pool, it's possible ?
I don't want to make situation with 2 pools